# Spring EL Expression to return boolean value

Tags: spring-el, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to dynamically configure the createIndex flag:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{@myindex}", createIndex = "#{@shouldIndex}")
public class MyDocument {
...
}
```

This throws an error because createIndex expects boolean. Is there any way to return boolean type from el expression?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a question of SpEL returning `boolean`; the property is hard-wired as a `boolean`...

```
    boolean createIndex() default true;
```

So it can't be determined at runtime; it won't accept a SpEL expression, which is a String.

Comment: is there a way to set this property on runtime? This seems like a major design flaw.

Comment: I am not familiar with the project nor if it would make sense to make this configurable; I am just speaking to the Java realities; I suggest you raise a new feature suggestion on the [project's JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES).